# trying to get all imgs from web python + bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

First of all I'll say that, as my code comments are in Spanish, I'll try to explain them in English even though the code is pretty obvious and easy to understand. Don't feel insulted if I'm explaining things that are too obvious :)

So I'm trying to get all img from a website but it seems it just doesn't want to. I've read some similar articles but none seem to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
```

You can visit the web and see the html yourself.

```
# url de las imgs
url = 'https://dbz.space/cards/'
```

Here request the web page for it to be parsed

```
# descargamos la pagina para scrapear
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

Here I search for all the images with that class

```
# localizamos todas las imgs con esa clase
image_tags = soup.findAll("img", {"class": "thumb on"})
```

Here i just look if the folder imgs exist and if it doesn't then create one to then go inside it

```
# si no existe imgs lo creamos
if not os.path.exists('imgs'):
    os.makedirs('imgs')

# cambiamos de directorio
os.chdir('imgs')
```

A variable for then naming all images

```
# para el nombre de la imagen
x = 0
```

And finally the saving process

```
# guardando imagenes
for image in image_tags:
    try:
        url = image['src']
        response = requests.get(url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open('img-' + str(x) + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(requests.get(url).content)
                f.close()
                x += 1
        print('Nueva imagen en carpeta')

    except:
        pass
```

So, the imgs on the web are inside a div tag and they have the class "thumb on" and they also contain the src (obviously) link which is the one I want to get to my folder called "imgs"

Comment: Are you sure the `src` tags aren't loaded asynchronously by Javascript?

Comment: Mmmm wow i didn't even thought about it... Is there any solution then?

Comment: Selenium webdriver would be the library you'd want in that case

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the URL of the image file itself...

```
> <img class="thumb on"
> src="https://dbz.s3.amazonaws.com/v2/global/character/thumb/card_1011720_thumb.png">
```

Then simply...

```
yourBSobj.find("img", {"class": "thumb on"}).attrs['src']
```

I would use find_all() actually so you can iterate through a loop of images, do your processing/saving etc and then see your results afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @cricket_007 said, the `img` tags are indeed loaded asynchronously by JavaScript. But, there is no need of using `Selenium`.

Upon inspection, you can see that each `img` tag is located inside this tag:

```
<div class="..." res="..." base="..." aim="" quantity="" release="1" imgur="x">
```

This tag is available in the source code (i.e. Not loaded by JavaScript). Here, we can get the `x` value which is a part of the imgur URL. One example:

```
<div class="..." res="1010160" base="1010161" aim="" quantity="" release="1" imgur="yK0wNs3">
```

After getting the `imgur` value, you can make the URL like this:

```
'https://i.imgur.com/{}.png'.format(imgur)
```

As the URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp7B5.png.

Complete code:

```
r = requests.get('https://dbz.space/cards/')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

if not os.path.exists('imgs'):
    os.makedirs('imgs')
os.chdir('imgs')

i = 0
for item in soup.find_all('div', imgur=True):
    imgur = item['imgur']
    if imgur:
        r = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/{}.png'.format(imgur))
        with open('img-{}.jpg'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        i += 1
```

Partial Output:

[image]

**Note:** I'm using `f.write(r.content)` and not `f.write(requests.get(url).content)`. There's no need to send one more request.

Comment: @Majeteosorio, I've tested this code (kept it running till the end) and it downloaded all the images without any errors. So, you can use this code as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much, really apreciate your help. The only thing happening now is that it pops this error 
`File "pilla.py", line 6, in <module> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined`
I don't get why Because I'm importing everything in the correct way. `import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import os`

Comment: Either change your import to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` or change `BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')` to `bs(r.text, 'lxml')`. And if you get error for `lxml`, install it- `pip install lxml` or change it to`html.parser`.

Comment: Ok finally discovered it by my self XD but thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

So the error that poped saying `File "pilla.py", line 6, in <module> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined`
Is solved by changing on the variable `soup` `BeautifulSoup` for `bs` and `lxlm` for `html.parser` Complete code is right here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

r = requests.get('https://dbz.space/cards/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

if not os.path.exists('imgs'):
    os.makedirs('imgs')
os.chdir('imgs')

i = 0
for item in soup.find_all('div', imgur=True):
    imgur = item['imgur']
    if imgur:
        r = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/{}.png'.format(imgur))
        with open('img-{}.jpg'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        i += 1
```

Thank you all very much for the help. Really apreciate it :)